# How to pass parameters from html.erb to a different html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm playing with the messenger gem in rails 4.

I have a graph of nodes and I want to be able to bring up a message box (initially in a different page but will make it a partial later) when a node is pressed so that the current user can message that node.

The id for the clicked node is kept in a div called `NameID`

At the moment all I've got working is a button that opens the new message page and then you can choose a user from a drop down list. I guess I want that drop down list- the recipient- to be prepopulated from the currently clicked node on the index page.

Here is what I have so far:

index.html.erb

```
<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="BtnMessageNode" href="/messages/new">Start conversation</a></p>

<div id=NameID><<THIS IS POPULATED BY JAVASCRIPT>></div>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @chosen_recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]
  end

  def create
    recipients = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end
end
```

helpers/messages_helper.rb

```
module MessagesHelper
  def recipients_options(chosen_recipient = nil)
    s = ''
    User.all.each do |user|
      s << "<option value='#{user.id}' data-img-src='#{gravatar_image_url(user.email, size: 50)}' #{'selected' if user == chosen_recipient}>#{user.name}</option>"
    end
    s.html_safe
  end
end
```

messages/new.html.erb

```
<% page_header "Start Conversation" %>

<%= form_tag messages_path, method: :post do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'message[subject]', 'Subject' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'message[subject]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'message[body]', 'Message' %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'message[body]', nil, cols: 3, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'recipients', 'Choose recipients' %>
    <%= select_tag 'recipients', recipients_options(@chosen_recipient), multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it' %>
  </div>

  <%= submit_tag 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Include the code for `recipients_options`

Comment: Its part of the mailboxer gem so I don't have the code- it basically provides a drop down with all the users in it

Comment: Usually when you use `method options_from_collection_for_select ` you would pass the `selected` option:  `<%= select_tag 'recipients', options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, selected: @chosen_recipient), multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it' %>` It might work with mailboxer metohd but otherwise you'll have to dig into the gem.

Comment: Aha- I found it as a helper- I've added it to the code above

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to pass parameters to GET routes:

### A. Named segments

`/users/:user_id/message/new`

This nested route would be great if you are sending a message to a single user.

### B. Query parameters

Rails supports query parameters as well:

`/message/new?to=2`

Rails automatically adds query parameters to the `params` hash. So in this case you would do `params[:to]`.

You can use the Rails route helpers so that you don't have to deal with encoding urls yourself:

```
new_message_path(to: @user.id)
```

Use query params for optional parameters like filters and sorting or in this case a preset. Don't use them like `users?id=5`.